# file_get_contents against symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, file-get-contents

I have a `file_get_contents($myUrl)` call from a flat PHP script that isn't working.

If I run `$myUrl` in a browser it works fine, if I do it over the `file_get_contents()` it behaves as if the url is incorrect or incomplete.

The myUrl looks like this

```
https://login.myApp.com/getWifiSettings/ofBoSf593f
```

Where the last part is a token, and the sym2 webApp behaves as if that token is incorrect, the same way as if I were to paste everything but the last character in the browser (thus producing an incorrect token).

I don't know whether this is an issue caused by the file_get_contents() (do I need any parameters with it to work?) or if it is some security setting in my sym2 installation that denies access for such a call (how does it distinguish between a user's web browser calling the route and a script using file_get_contents to access the route?)

Comment: A login usually uses cookies to store a session id. `file_get_contents()` isn't able to handle cookie requests well.

Comment: _same way as if I were to paste everything but the last character in the browser_ -- are you using that as an example of how you might break it manually, or do you literally mean that the last character is stripped?

Comment: How is the Symfony application supposed to handle the token? Does it use it merely for data retrieval, or is it needed to build a persistent session (which probably requires a cookie)?

Comment: No login/cookie/session, the token is merely used for data retrieval. Nothing is stripped, I'm just saying the webapp's response is the same as if I were to break it intentionally be removing a character from the token

Comment: @Sven, how come file_get_contents can't handle cookies ? what about the second argument and using `stream_context_create`

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd You may be able to do it, but not easily. That's what I mean with "handle well". Its complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to us trim() on the string before you submit it to file_get_contents. It may be that a whitespace character is in the variable and is being submitted and interpreted as part of the URL.